# How can I get a text inside of an div element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to get a text from `div` element by clicking on the `input`:

```
<td>
<div class="modal-col s4 m12 modal-html">
<div class="text">Text I needed</div>
</div>
<input type="image" src="/Content/images/filedel.png" class="delete-file" />
</td>
```

This doesn't work, need ur help to fix it

```
var name = $(this).closest('.text').text();
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` refer to?? `.modal-html` ?? ..

Comment: `<input>` of course

Comment: Why would you say "of course"? You posted no event handler code.

Comment: yes @j08691 I don't know why *of course*

Comment: sorry, I thought you would understand when I've used in description words like "by clicking on the input"

Comment: @LabLab you're right .. sorry my bad I didn't notice it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use `$(this).parent().find('.text').text();` This will find the class text inside the `td`

```js
$('input').click(function(){
   var name = $(this).parent().find('.text').text();
   console.log(name)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
<div class="modal-col s4 m12 modal-html">
  <div class="text">Text I needed</div>
</div>
<input type="image" src="/Content/images/filedel.png" class="delete-file" />
</td>
```

Comment: thanks, it helped me. Get your reputation increased)

Answer (score 0):

You can Add an id to the div element and then access the element with the selector:

```
<div class="text" id="MyText">Text I needed</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myText = $("#MyText").html();
```

Some [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)